# Does rel=prefetch do anything when updated on the fly?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, fetch-api, prefetch

I'm doing pagination with api calls and trying to use link prefetch to speed it up. It's surely supposed to work with the first iteration, that comes with the original page load, but I'm not sure whether browsers do anything with it when it's changed on the fly with js.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- this is to prefetch the next 10 results. supposedly, it _should_ help -->
<link id="pagination" href="https://example.com/api/items?limit=10&offset=10" rel="prefetch" as="fetch">
</head>
<body>
<main>
<!-- here are the first 10 results populated by default -->
<article>[template]</article> <!-- (x10) -->
<!-- more to be inserted here -->
</main>
<!-- the trigger -->
<button onclick="more()">See more</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
<script>
let offset = 10
let increment = 10
let limit = 10

function more() {

// getting the items
fetch(`https://example.com/api/items?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        let results = response.data

// [just pseudo-templating here]
        output = ''
        results.forEach(function (result) {
            output += '<article>[template]</article>'
        })

// updating the page
        document.querySelector('main').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', output)
    })

// updating variable for the next button click
  offset = offset + increment

// get that prefetch link in the head
  let fetchlink = document.getElementById('pagination')

// update it on the fly with info for the next page (offset value changes every time)
  fetchlink['href'] = fetchlink['href'].replace(/(offset=)[^\&]+/, '$1' + offset);

// so it becomes "<link id="pagination" href="https://example.com/api/items?limit=10&offset=20" rel="prefetch" as="fetch">" and then ..."30"... and so on.

}
</script>
```

So, would those last two lines be of any help at all?

**Update**

My chrome console's network tab looks something like this:

[image: Tested with a single item at a time]

The link prefetch is loaded as *type json*. Then, on click, the actual fetch comes up again as *type fetch*, also triggering the next prefetch as *type json*. Curiously enough, the last fetch is no longer actually executed, while the payload **does** get displayed properly.

So not quite sure if this either works fully, or not at all, or everything gets duplicated except for the last item.

Well, for every "duplicated" fetch, the status *is* *200 OK (from prefetch cache)* so this suggests that the intended job just might actually get done.

**Update2**

rel="preload" seems to work fine (single network event for each request), although that's not really intuitive when checked against specs (neither hurry nor certainty with pagination) and does trigger the warning *"The resource [...] was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.*

Comment: Sidenote: If you use `as="fetch"` you should also include the `crossorigin` attribute as stated in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-as)

Comment: indeed, thanks, will do

Comment: ...well, most likely it works fine, at least with chrome, all I had to do was to check _network_ in the browser console :blush: